# Why Eclipse open some files in readonly mode?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just started to use Eclipse (for Android development) - so I am pretty new to this IDE and I don't understand some things. Sometimes (often - while or after debug) I found some my files with code in readonly mode - I can't edit my code. I see "Read-Only" label in status bar - but I don't know when exactly and why this file became read-only. I can't do anything with this file and have to close it and find once again in project tree and open - then I can edit it. I am forced to do it every few minutes - so I don't like this behaviour.

Why this happens? What can I do to avoid it? How to make file in editor editable from read-only mode?

Comment: This usually happens if the file was edited outside of the Eclipse IDE. Are you or is some other process editing the file?

Comment: please check the files from the directory, it may possible the files are Read-only.. I never faced such problems.

Comment: No editing files outside IDE and no Read-only flags. More ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens while debugging and following code. Eclipse will open `.class` files, Most of the time `.class` files are the source of libraries you are using, sometimes they are the generated `.class` of your own code, that's why you cannot edit them. . Although it is your code; if you want to edit it you should go to your own source (`.java`)

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen when you use a "pessimistic" source control system like ClearCase, or when the file itself is marked as read-only in the file system.